# Mapreduce on indexed google data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, search-engine

Is MapReduce the reason for the instant search results produced by google or is it just used to index the massive web page data ? I mean is MApreduce at work behind every search query that I enter ? 
I was confused because to my understanding there is a latency associated with running Hadoop so it can not be the tool used the seach the indexed data for a query.

Answer (score 2):

MapReduce was used by Google until 2010 to build the search index. Your search query is fired against that index which then returns quick responses. The issue with MapReduce was, that the update frequency was too low to keep up with the updates of the web.
Since 2010 Google uses [Caffeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Google_Caffeine), which is based on [BigTable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigtable). See also [here](https://googleblog.blogspot.de/2010/06/our-new-search-index-caffeine.html) and [here](http://www.howgoogleworks.net).